# php store array in array by reference

Tags: php

I have the following problem. There are some php lines.

In the var_dump of `$testArrayA`, the "def" entry with `test2` is NOT there because it was added
after `$testArrayB` was added to `$testArrayA`.

It seems to me that in my case, that `$testArrayB` is not stored by reference in `$testArrayA`. How can I store it per reference, what do I have to make to have "def" entry in the var_dump?

Thanks alot in advance

```
$testArrayA = [];
$testArrayB = [];
$testArrayB["ghi"] = "test1";
$testArrayA["abc"] = $testArrayB;
$testArrayB["def"] = "test2";
```

The var_dump:

```
array(1) {
  ["abc"]=>
    array(1) {
       ["ghi"]=>
       string(5) "test1"
      }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is simply a matter of passing by reference:

```
$testArrayA = [];
$testArrayB = [];
$testArrayB["ghi"] = "test1";
$testArrayA["abc"] = &$testArrayB;
$testArrayB["def"] = "test2";
```

var_dump($testArrayA);

```
array (size=1)
'abc' => &
array (size=2)
  'ghi' => string 'test1' (length=5)
  'def' => string 'test2' (length=5)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
$testArrayA["abc"] = &$testArrayB;
```

***Note:***

Different with C's pointer, references in PHP are a means to access the same variable content by different names.

Answer (score 1):

in the php manual

Array assignment always involves value copying. Use the reference operator to copy an array by reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
$testArrayA = null;
$testArrayB = null;
$testArrayB["ghi"] = "test1";
$testArrayA["abc"] = $testArrayB;
$testArrayB["def"] = "test2";
print_r($testArrayA);
echo ("<br>");
print_r($testArrayB);


Array ( [abc] => Array ( [ghi] => test1 ) ) 
Array ( [ghi] => test1 [def] => test2 )
```

The 'def' entry is a different reference with the 'ghi',
but they all belong testArrayB.

$testArrayA["abc"] = $testArrayB;

This code only is value reference ,not address reference.